# Update :Result is not transfered to the orginal dataset. Sorting Rows in Dataset using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ado.net, dataset

Update: even though I have got the required result but when the the second function access the data table the value is still the same
It a sequential program with two functions in different classes. First sort and second replace function. So it should sort the value and other function should be able to retrieve the sorted table but when it retrieve the datatable it gives the unsorted table.

I have used acceptchanges() but it also give the same result.

The program is trying to sort the table according to the required field and the result is stored in Sorted table variable. I am trying to copy this to the original i-e sourceTables but it is not working and is adding another row instead of updating [As shown in below dig]. I have tried to copy whole table but it does not work and by adding rows it is not giving the required result. I have used different methods but I am not getting the required result.

```
List<DataTable> sourceTables =   context.GetDataByTable(sourceTable.StringValue);
List<DataTable> targetTables = context.GetDataByTable(targetTable.StringValue, sourceTables.Count);

        string orderDesc= orderField.StringValue + " DESC";


        for (int i = 0; i < sourceTables.Count; i++)
        {
            DataView dv = sourceTables[i].DefaultView;

            if (orderDirection.StringValue == OrderDirectionAsc)
            {
                // for Sorting in Ascending Order 
                dv.Sort = orderField.StringValue;
            }

            else
            {
                // for Sorting in Descending Order
                dv.Sort = orderDesc;
            }


            DataTable sortedTable = dv.ToTable();

            DataTable dttableNew = sortedTable.Clone();
            //sourceTables[i] = sortedTable.Copy();
            //targetTables[i] = dv.ToTable();
            //targetTables[i] = sortedTable.Copy();
            // foreach (DataRow dr in sortedTable.Rows)
            ////  targetTables[i].Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
            //}
            for (int j = 0; j < sourceTables[i].Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (sourceTable.GetValue().ToString() == targetTable.GetValue().ToString())
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in sortedTable.Rows)
                    {
                        targetTables[i].Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

                    }                  
                else
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in sortedTable.Rows)
                    {
                        targetTables[i].Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

                    }

                    // targetTables[i] = sortedTable.Copy();  does not work

                    //foreach (DataRow drtableOld in sortedTable.Rows)
                    //{
                    // targetTables[i].ImportRow(drtableOld);
                    //}
```

Instead of replacing the first values it is adding more rows

[image]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you need to copy the sorted view to anything?

Comment: I am trying to sort the table. As the sort function does not work on the datatable. So after sorting the view I am trying to replace original dataable with the view.

Comment: if I use sourceTables[i]= dv.ToTable() the cahnges are only local

Comment: @Plutonix Can you please suggest something

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Data is very often stored differently in the db than how it is used or shows to the user.  That never requires copying data to another table.

Comment: I am working on a module in which there are different operations for dataset like replace, combine split table etc. I am trying to make a function which takes a table sort it and replace the original table with a sorted table.For example a user wants to apply some function he takes a table and applies sorting and replace function(replace two column) on it.

Comment: These are all separate functions which can be used together. When I first replace and than applies my sorting it works but when I does the opposite it doesn't. for example. Sort and transfer. First it should sort which it does if I look through debug but when debugs jumps to second function it retrieves the data table but function retrieves the original datatable instead of the sorted one.

Comment: I dont want to copy data table I just want the sorted table to be retrieved when I call second function, Is it something I am missing ??

Answer (score 1):

If any one have problem with duplicate data or the changes are only local and is not effecting the original data table. Remember to always use .ImportRow(dr) function to add rows to the table and if you use Tables[i].Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray); the changes will affect only the local table and not the original one. Use .clear to remove the old rows from the orginal table. The action done directly on the original function will only effect the rows. If it is done on the clone copy changes will nor affect the original table.
Here is the complete code

```
           DataTable sortTable = dv.ToTable();

            if (sTable.GetValue().ToString() == tTable.GetValue().ToString())
            {

                sTables[i].Clear();

                foreach (DataRow dr in sortTable.Rows)

                {
                    sTables[i].ImportRow(dr);
                }

                sTables[i].AcceptChanges();

            }
```